# How to run the query stored as a value in a row using Stored procedure for some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one table with 3 columns. One column captures the case no., one column captures all the DML (Insert / Update /Delete) query date wise for the specific case and one column captures the respective date and time at which the DML was performed. Now the row can repeat for a single case as it captures any DML performed for that case.

My requirement is that I have to write a procedure with Case No. and / or Date Time as a input parameter and after executing the procedure it must take all the DML query till the specific date and executes it as normal DML query.

Below is the sample table for the same:

[image]

For above case 1, I want to run all the dml statement for any specific date. Please help in this case.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, do not find any option to create a table from the editor.

Comment: Simply put an empty row before the data, and also have 4 <space> first in each row. (OR, mark the data and click `{}`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following schema and records:

```
create table caseLog 
(
    CaseID INT,
    Query NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Date] DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE Cases
(ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(50))


INSERT INTO caseLog (CaseID, Query, [Date])
VALUES 
(1, 'INSERT INTO Cases (ID, Name) VALUES  (1, ''First Name'')', '2019-04-02 15:00'),
(1, 'UPDATE Cases SET Name = ''Second Name'' WHERE ID = 1', '2019-04-02 16:00'),
(1, 'UPDATE Cases SET Name = ''Third Name'' WHERE ID = 1', '2019-04-02 17:00');
```

The procedure could look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE executeCaseLog
    @CaseID INT,
    @Until DATETIME
AS
DECLARE
    @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
BEGIN

    SELECT @Query += CONCAT(caseLog.Query, ';', CHAR(13), CHAR(10))
      FROM caseLog
     WHERE caseID = @CaseID
       AND [Date] <= @Until

    -- For showcase purposes
    PRINT @Query

    EXEC sp_executesql @Query

END;
GO
```

Now, if executed like so:

```
EXEC executeCaseLog @CaseID = 1, @Until = '2019-04-02 16:30'
```

It will yield the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Cases

ID          Name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Second Name

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Best explanation. Thankyou

Comment: One clarification when I am using <= expression, its not taking the condition, its taking just lower date than the given date, I want it to take for the inputted date also.